Throwing Expressions: The Under-Taught Art of Algebraic Sculpting
I've come to realize, in my dotage after a whole career carrying out utilitarian algebra and calculus, there there is a specific algebraic skill that they never specifically teach you, that turns out the be the one you actually need.
Algebra up to calculus is all about "simplification" - at least that's what they're constantly telling you, but the algebra you need in calculus (and actually in general, although they don't put it this way), is actually more like ... I don't really have a word for this ... more like pottery, or perhaps more generally, clay working, where you're trying to get to something elegant that you can't really see yet, and you do it by adding clay on and taking clay off and turning the thing over in your hands. Maybe this metaphor is a bit distant. I'm thinking of things like where you use what they call "big ones" to turn rational expressions into something that you can then take apart into something that turns out to be simpler. (A common use case being rationalization, but there's a million of these patterns and manipulaitons.) It is, I guess, simplification in the abstract, but you often have to complexify the expression to get to the simpler form, and tear it apart in various ways.
I know that it's commonly said that you often have to make things more complex to make them simpler, and I know well how to do this in practice, in my day-to-day work  I do it all the time without even thinking about it, but I feel like there's a missing textbook called something like "Throwing Expressions" (like throwing pots :-) Does such a book exist?
Commenters have quite reasonably asked for examples. There are, of course, a literal infinitude of these, and I guess what I'm actually asking for is a collection of intersting ones. Here are some that I have just run into in my work only today (!), but these are not terribly elegant. The book I imagine would be a collection of elegant ones, but hopefully these will serve as prompts for folks to contribute nicer ones.
There are some perfectly obvious cases that we all recognize, such as factoring of perfect squares, for example:
$9x^2-4cos(x)^2 \rightarrow (3 x - 2 cos(x)) (3 x + 2 cos(x))$
Then there's what I'll call "throwing powers", which is a bit less obvious:
$(\sqrt{3})^{4x} \rightarrow 3^{2x}$
And, of course, rationalization:
$ \frac{2x}{\sqrt{x}} \rightarrow \frac{2x}{\sqrt{x}}×\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}}  \rightarrow \frac{2x\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x}} \rightarrow  \frac{2x\sqrt{x}}{x} \rightarrow 2\sqrt{x}$
And once you get into trig there's comes a tidal wave of these.
You're going to -- perfectly reasonably -- say "Duh! That's just algebra!" But it's a particular kind of algebra that doesn't go the route they teach you in typical introductory algebra, which is to always head for simplification. Again, you're going to say "Duh!", and again I agree ... for US! But these sort of unfolding and separation and then refolding aren't really called out as being as elegant as they are.
To my mind these represent what is so magical about algebra; That as long as you follow the rules, which are pretty darned simple, you can play with the expression to your heart's content -- and, more importantly, you should get used to playing with them! To return to the sculpting metaphor, as long as physics pertains (which, in the clay case, physics ensures for you, so you need to do a little more work in algebra to make sure you don't break the rules), you can play with the clay, even returning it to a lump, and eventually you'll get to the elegant pot you've envisioned, if you are skilled enough. And getting to being skilled enough means making a lot of pots and screwing up a lot, but it should be fun along the way.
That's the book I want to write: "Algebra is Magic"

Since I don't understand what you try to communicate it seems  not easy to teach. So just start with the first part of the first chapter of the book you are looking for.

@trula I think it's easier to teach than to describe. (To your point! :-) Starting with a chapter is a good idea.

So describe what you teach!

Some examples might help us understand what you're talking about.

@gidds Fair enough. I've added some examples, but I'm really looking to find a lot more, these are just the ones I happened to come across just in my work today!

In your first example, the LHS uses 10 symbols and requires 6 operations, while the RHS uses 20 symbols and requires 9 operations (if I've counted correctly).  Can you explain why the RHS counts as ‘simpler’ here? —  But is your wider question more along the lines of “What rules or processes can we follow to make an expression simpler?”, or “Why isn't it obvious how to make an expression simpler?”?

What's the question?

This is an almost impressionistic post which is hard to take away a concrete question from.  However, it does move me to comment on things like $\frac{x+7}{x-1} = \frac{x-1+8}{x-1} = 1 + \frac{8}{x-1}$ which are often not explicitly taught but are quite useful.  Or $\frac{n^2 + 1}{n^3+1} < \frac{n^2 + n^2}{n^3} = \frac{2}{n}$ for $n \geq 1$.  These bits of algebra are often baffling to students when I use them.  They involve "adding some clay before removing another bit".

@StevenGubkin A+ These are perfect examples of what I'm looking for. Your first example just makes me warm all over! (They're both very nice!) I feel like I need to create a web page with hundreds of these sorts of non-obvious manipulations that students can engage with. BTW, the place where these start showing up in multitudes is calculus (or pre-calculus limits) where you need to cope with complicated denominators that are zero -- until you figure out how to take them apart.

Here's the essential problem.  Algebra of course makes best sense as a bunch of things one can do, and then a student has to decide for themselves which of these things one should do to solve a problem.  However, this requires creativity and ingenuity on the part of the student.  What is one supposed to do for the 60% of students who simply don't have any creativity and whose brains cannot do anything other than follow directions given by someone else?    If you want those 60% to also graduate, then you have to give them something they can do to prove they have at least been paying attention.

@AlexanderWoo I think that the 100% of student would learn a LOT about algebra, and have a LOT of fun with it if this sort of  -- what to my mind is magical! -- manipulation was taught as a fun subskill. I did initially have in mind just writing a book (or significantly less ambitiously creating a web site), so the 60% don't have to go there if they don't want to, but the 40% could.

I.m going to try to engage with your post, although it is incredibly loosely written.  Such that it's hard to even tell what you are asserting ("not even wrong").  On top of that, it feels like walking through taffy.  [I'm not even sure if your examples are clay throwing or simplification, which you are trying to contrast with!]
OK.  I basically think you have a good point.  In other words, there is no clear directionality of how algebraic expressions should be transformed.  Sometimes it is better to express something as the difference of cubes.  Sometimes as the factored out form.
However (BUT), nobody on the "normal algebra" side is advocating only being able to go in one direction.  As the comments point out, the different expressions are helpful for different questions.  Sometimes you want things factored out, sometimes you don't (and the same with power laws or trig identities!)
You are fighting a straw man to think that math teachers (or mathematicians) don't already get this.  How do you think Newton invented calculation of pi or Euler invented [insert several tricky algebra derivations], without some strong ability to play with the clay (squishing it, adding some on and taking some off later, etc. etc.)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gMlf1ELvRzc
or
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JAr512hLsEU
Part of all the homework drill and different topics of algebra/calculus is to give the student experience of how to transform expressions in different ways and in different directions.  And really the normal, classical, curriculum already does this all over the place.
E.g. as someone pointed out on a different question, the "I'll derive everything" approach to trig identities can be an issue if you don't also recognize things "in reverse" (which may be needed in the middle of some calculus problem).  Or you can look at integration by parts, where the WHOLE TECHNIQUE is based on throwing a little more clay on the wheel to cancel out some problems of the pot.  But integration by parts is a standard part of the curriculum and was developed very quickly in the late 1600s, shortly after initial publication of the calculus by Leibnitz.

Thanks for engaging with the question, and your point about directionality is, I think, what I'm trying to say. (But "You are fighting a straw man to think that math teachers (or mathematicians) don't already get this. ..." FTR, I explicitly stated that I get that mathematicians and math teachers already get this. This is a math ed forum, so I'm concerned primarily with the fact that it isn't explicitly taught as a critical and separable skill.)

It's cool, man.  And thanks for not being too sensitive about the negative remarks (these kids these days, sheesh!)  I would just be a little wary of the "general skill fallacy".  There's a fair amount of research showing that general problem solving skills are overrated.  And that what enables problem solving is very domain specific.  And really supported more by deep exposure to the topic itself, rather than "critical thinking" or "problem solving skills".

For the most part I agree with you regarding general and specific PS skills, although there clearly are some general problem solving skills (I teach CogSci at an Ivy Plus, so we could get into this in much more detail than anyone, including us want, so let's just leave it you're not wrong! :-) I guess what I was getting at isn't the general/specific issue (although I did say that, wrongly) but more that there isn't a lot of practice on just free-from algebraic manipulation like this, which is what I think is a hole in math ed. Back to cogsci, separate practice on subskills is extremely useful.
